# Check if a string variable is a subset of another variable in R

Tags: r

I want to check if one variable (data type: string) is a subset of another variable (also string) in R. For example,
var1=Subject02_Aufnahme000.csv
var2=Subject02\Subject02_Aufnahme000.csv
And what I'm trying to do is:
if (var1 is a subset of var2) { print("True")}.

How to check if var1 is a subset of var2 in R. Is there any function or any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grepl` from base R

```
var1 <- "Subject02_Aufnahme000.csv" 
var2 <- "Subject02\\Subject02_Aufnahme000.csv"
grepl(var1,var2)
[1] TRUE
```